# How to check in which Y coordinate are intersecting two Rect?

Tags: java, android, math, rect

Having two views represented by two `Rect` in Android, I'm checking if they are touching doing this:

```
Rect.intersects(rect1, rect2);
```

`rect1` is (400, 500, 500, 0) and `rect2` is (450, 240, 475, 260).

Which is the best way to calculate in which `Y coordinate` are the two rect touching?

Comment: Try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect#intersect(android.graphics.Rect)

Comment: I didn't get your point, could you show the expected output with given `rect1` and `rect2`?